# How to apply Colchine for doubling the ploidy of plants

Tags: houseplants

Same as title, I am wondering how to do this for making seedless plants

Comment: There is some information on this subject near the bottom, under Botanical Use in this link - note its Colchicine, not colchine...  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colchicine

Comment: Hi, @Aravind Karthigeyan! I think it would be better if you asked this question on Biology SE because ploidy alteration by using colchicine requires specific safety measures (fume hood) and therefore you would get a more useful answer there. You can also edit the question to keep only the part with hybridization for seedless plants, and if so, we can keep here the question. Whatever you decide, I suggest to add the name of a crop, otherwise the question will also be too broad.

Comment: The short answer: changing the number of chromosomes changes the DNA and so the deep reproductive mechanism. Many plants see something wrong [e.g. as a different species] and so it will not reproduce, so no seeds. Polyploids has the advantages (usually) to create larger plants (more identical chromosomes, so more parallel proteins). The details are outside the scope of this group: check biology.SE

Comment: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/80347/i-am-planning-to-breed-strawberries-and-raspberries-how-do-i-use-colchicine-to/80351?noredirect=1#comment143013_80351

Comment: I closed this as you also posted on Biology where you will get a better answer